# Birt - How to Format Y axis as percentage

Tags: birt

In the chart below I'm trying to make the percent_uptime column be formatted on the chart's Y axis be shown as a percent.  E.g, "35%" instead of "0.35".

Any ideas how to do this?  I tried changing the Series 1 function to use the formatter.format function but then I get an error about strings not allowed on the Y axis :-(

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to change the `Value (Y) Series:` on the `Select Data` tab (as illustrated in the question) from `row["percent_uptime"]`, to `row["percent_uptime"]*100` (by pressing the `fx` button and amending the formula accordingly).

Alternatively, if you want to include the % symbol as part of the label for each value on the y-axis:

- select the `Format Chart` tab in the dialog;
- select `Value (Y) Series` (under `Series`) in the left hand pane of the dialog;
- click on the `Labels` button in the right hand pane of the dialog;
- in the `Series Labels` dialog that appears, select `Value Data` in the `Values` list on the right and click on the `Format` button;
- select the `Standard` radio button in the `Edit Format` dialog that appears and specify the following values:

  - `Suffix:` %
  - `Multiplier:` 100
- click OK throughout the dialogs to confirm applying the changes.

Comment: Thanks.  Your alternate instructions seem to only affect labels placed over each value, not the axis.

Comment: @Greg: Yes - as stated in the answer ("if you want to include the % symbol as part of the label for each value on the y-axis") and as implied in the question ("I'm trying to make the percent_uptime column be formatted on the chart's Y axis be shown as a percent. E.g, "35%" instead of "0.35" ")

Comment: So there's no way to get a % as a suffix on the actual Y axis?  (Your solution is probably good enough for me though. Thanks again)

Comment: @Greg: As a suffix of what? You can put a % as the label for the whole Y axis by selecting `Y-Axis` (under `Axis`, under `Chart Area`) in the left hand pane of the `Format Chart` tab of the dialog, checking the `Visible` check box next to the Title and entering % as the Title under `Y-Axis` in the right hand pane of the dialog.